# How to use the fig_caption in Rmd to odt export?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

According to [rmarkdown.rstudio](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/odt_document_format.html) in the Rmd to odt export

> fig_caption controls whether figures are rendered with captions

How can I make use of that?  The `fig.cap` chunk option -- while being rendered in pdf -- is ignored in the odt export.

Comment: I have tested it on my machine, and it's working here.

Comment: Thanks for checking.  Time to upgrade for me I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the confirmation by @J_F that it should work I now checked my pandoc version.

- pandoc 1.12 does not produce captions in odt
- pandoc 1.13 does not produce captions in odt
- pandoc 1.17 *does* produce captions in odt

So it really is the pandoc version and upgrading did solve my problem at last.